# jQuery Ajax for an autocomplete in alfresco

Tags: jquery, ajax, alfresco

i need to implement an autocomplete input in Alfresco, but i need to do an
ajax request with jquery, someone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are you trying to use jQuery? Alfresco uses YUI library. If you like to, have a look at [my older post on creating autocompletion](http://www.shmoula.cz/mvc-and-spring-surf/) in Spring Surf (Alfresco Share) based on that library. If you still demand jQuery, [it should not be](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/) a big problem to rewrite that few javascript routines.